# Why does the Sudarshana Chakra resemble a tantric yantra in this image?

Tags: identification-request, sudarsana

[image: Lord Vishnu holding Sudarshana & other items]

In the above image, the Sudarshana Chakra looks like a tantric yantra. Is there any scriptural reason behind this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]We get the following invocation Mantra for Sudarshana from [this PDF](http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/pancharatraprayoga.pdf):

> śaṅkhaṁ cakraṁ ca cāpaṁ paraśuṁ asimiśuṁ śūla pāśāṁ kuśāṁśca |
>   bibhrānam vajra keṭaṁ hala musula gadā kuṇṭaṁ atyugra daṁṣṭraṁ ||
>   jvālā keśaṁ trinetraṁ jvaladānala nibhaṁ hāra keyūra bhūṣam |
>   dhyāyet **śaṭkona** saṁsthaṁ sakala ripu-kula prāṇa saṁhāra cakram ||
>
> I visualize   Sudarshana
>   the   eliminator  of  all hostile forces, located within  the **six-cornered  star**,
>   bearing    the    conch,  discus, bow,    axe, sword,
>   trident,  noose,  goad,   the diamond-shield, plough, cudgel, mace, spear,
>   with  aweful  sharp   fangs,  with    blazing halo,   three   eyes,
>   the   intensity   of a    raging  inferno,    adorned with     garlands and   anklets.

This Shatkona is also found in the [Sudarshana Yantra](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81bhijDOJ1L._SX425_.jpg), which is worshipped as the Sudarshana Chakra.

In the image given in the question too, we can see a Shatkona (six-pointed star). So, they have drawn it roughly as per the Dhyana Sloka.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, sudarshan chakra is a manifestation of Narayan's *Ida* and *Pingala* naadi. Shiva, the *Adiyogi*, taught Narayan the way to use power of these Naadis as a weapon, in the form of boon to His *Tapasyaa*. And as we know that these Naadis are used to enlighten the 7 chakras in body. So, one can use power of Chakras and Naadis(in Sanskrit, this thing is mentioned as *Yogshakti*) in such a way(like a weapon), if learned from any *Siddh* yogi(Here, Shiva Himself). Henceforth, sudarshan chakra is represented as Tantric Chakra because both the systems are conveying similar messages, i.e., using Chakras and Naadis efficiently.

Comment: A verse would be useful if you can quote

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.As Akshay S said, quoting a verse or citing some scriptural source woould be appreciated.